# JQuery Trigger in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I would just like to ask, what is the equivalent of trigger in Javascript ?

ex.

```
$(this).trigger('move', 
  {
     x: event.pageX, 
     y: event.pageY
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) should be able to accomplish what you have above:

```
$(this).animate({ "left": event.pageX, "top": event.pageY }, 1000);
```

Or to move it instantaneously

```
$(this).animate({ "left": event.pageX, "top": event.pageY }, 0);
```

Just make sure whatever you're moving has `position:absolute` set.

Comment: @AJNaidas - I know, but it looks like you're trying to move an element to a new location.  The code above should do that.

Comment: $('#camera').bind('move-viewport', function(evt, movedMouse) - I would like to call that function using javascript. And i'll be converting that to cameraVar.addEventListener('move-viewport', function(evt, movedMouse) afterwards.

Comment: @AJNaidas: Why can't you use `trigger`?

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to save a pointer to a callback function when you bind and then simply call that callback function on trigger.

A really simple implementation would be:

```
({

  // save the function in an internal _callbacks object
  bind: function(name, callback) {
    this._callbacks || (this._callbacks = {});
    this._callbacks[name] || (this._callbacks[name] = []);
    this._callbacks[name].push(callback);
    return this;
  },

  // when triggering, look up the function and call it with the current context
  trigger: function(ev) {
    var callback, i;
    for (i = 0; _i < this._callbacks[ev]; i++) {
      callback = this._callbacks[ev][i];
      callback.apply(this, args); // this is the 'trigger' magic
    }
    return true;
  }

});
```